# Combine 2 sql table rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to combine the below rows into one record for a report. I am looking to get the [Loan Officer] and [Realtor] names to show on one line. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is where I am now

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.State
       ,z.County
       ,z.City
       ,cr.ZipCode
       ,cr.Route
       ,UPPER(c1.LastName) + ', ' + UPPER(c1.FirstName) AS 'Loan Officer'
       ,UPPER(c2.LastName) + ', ' + UPPER(c2.FirstName) AS 'Realtor'
       ,cr.ID
FROM Prospecting.ZipCodeCarrierRoute  cr WITH (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN ZIPCodes z WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON z.ZipCode = cr.ZipCode
       LEFT JOIN Prospecting.Contact_CarrierCode_Assignments cca WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON cca.ZipCodeCarrierRouteID = cr.ID
       LEFT JOIN Prospecting.Contact c1 WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON c1.ContactID = cca.ContactID
                     AND c1.ContactTypeID = 1
       LEFT JOIN Prospecting.Contact c2 WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON c2.ContactID = cca.ContactID
                     AND c2.ContactTypeID = 2
WHERE cr.ID = 875
```

This is the Results
[image]

This is what I an looking for
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can readily do this with `group by`:

```
SELECT z.State, z.County, z.City, cr.ZipCode, cr.Route,
       MAX(UPPER(c1.LastName) + ', ' + UPPER(c1.FirstName)) AS [Loan Officer],
       MAX(UPPER(c2.LastName) + ', ' + UPPER(c2.FirstName)) AS [Realtor],
       cr.ID
FROM Prospecting.ZipCodeCarrierRoute  cr WITH (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN ZIPCodes z WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON z.ZipCode = cr.ZipCode
       LEFT JOIN Prospecting.Contact_CarrierCode_Assignments cca WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON cca.ZipCodeCarrierRouteID = cr.ID
       LEFT JOIN Prospecting.Contact c1 WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON c1.ContactID = cca.ContactID
                     AND c1.ContactTypeID = 1
       LEFT JOIN Prospecting.Contact c2 WITH (NOLOCK)
              ON c2.ContactID = cca.ContactID
                     AND c2.ContactTypeID = 2
WHERE cr.ID = 875
GROUP z.State, z.County, z.City, cr.ZipCode, cr.Route, cr.ID
```

Comment: Excellent Gordon. I see the MAX you had on the names. Nice touch, I was headed down that road but was getting errors on the names. wasn't sure how to get around that.